# Set defaults for bootstrap datepicker in Meteor project

Tags: meteor, datepicker

First of all, Hi everyone, this is my first post/question,

I would like to set defaults in bootstrap datepicker in my Meteor project. I'm setting these in a functions.js file that is inside the client directory.
It works **fine** if I'm setting them apart like this:

```
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.autoclose = true;
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.todayHighlight = true;
```

But in a matter of doing things well, I would like it this way:

```
$.fn.datepicker.defaults = {
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true
}
```

However it just does not work. Did I miss something or is it just not possible in Meteor?

**Edit**: I forgot the say that I have several datepicker in different templates. And so the idea is to have the same behavior for all of them without duplicating the same default settings.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="my-datepicker">
```

Client JS:

```
Template.mytemplate.rendered=function() {
    $('#my-datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
});
}
```

Based on the meteor example found on https://atmospherejs.com/rajit/bootstrap3-datepicker and a bit of tinkering in the sandbox http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/

Hope this helps!